# Deployment slot not working in ASE in azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When we try to deploy web app to a deployment slot in app service plan(created inside app service environment) it removes the existing code in both production and staging slot and then it deploys the code in staging slot. Because of this our old code is not available in staging slot when we swap. Are we not supposed to use slot in ASE ? If yes, how can we fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same issue which was resolved after changing the task version of Azure App Service deploy task in the release pipeline. Earlier we were using the task version 4 which has option 'Deploy to slot or  ASE' which seems to cause the issue. When you select task version 3, you will get the option 'Deploy to slot' after which the release works fine and the code is not deleted  from staging or prod slot.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment slots are pretty standard and easy to use.

It sounds like your deployment process is broken and is not properly deploying in the correct sequence which is causing this issue.

I would suggest investigating your deployment process and taking it step by step and validating each step manually.

Edit:

The documentation you linked below is somewhat confusing to me however this looks to be the configuration you should try:

DeployToSlotOrASEFlag = TRUE
(We want to deploy to an ASE, so we must set TRUE)

SlotName = staging
(Required, if DeployToSlotOrASEFlag = true)
Default value: production

Comment: Initially that was my thought as well. Then I saw the explanation on the azure web app deploy task in the pipeline. It clearly says to put slot as "production" if you are deploying your web app in ASE.

Comment: Here is the link (DeployTo
SlotOrASEFlag explanation) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops

Comment: The documentation is confusing as there is some confusion between some of description however this is my understanding.. (updated in main body)

Comment: Yes, the document should put some more detail in this regard. So what happens in my case is, it is deploying to ASE and into the slot which I am mentioning in the task. Then I swap the slots with production slot to get my latest code in production slot.But before it put the latest code in the slot,it gets rid of my old code from production slot.So when I swap the slot, my staging slot contains nothing where it should have contained my old code. It works fine when I use ASP. This problem comes only when I use ASE.